# How can i set toggle my switch correctly on Ant Table List?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I using Ant Design Table. And inside of table i have Ant Switch. From my api i taking my Active-Passive status so default value coming like that like toggled or not. When i toggle it i making it reverse for "PUT" my api. But after i toggle 1 time (First toggle changing label but after it doesnt ) its toggling doesnt change label. How can i change that label ? My codes :

https://prnt.sc/1m8o4vn.

```
 const toggleChangeHandler = (value) => {
    value.Status = !value.Status;
    ApiService.FetchService(`Page`, "PUT", value);
  };
```

Its The Column on the table (Switch taking value from Status field) :

```
 {
          key: "4",
          title: "Durum",
          dataIndex: "Status",
          width: "20%",
          render: (completed, record) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <div className="flex">
                  <Switch
                    defaultChecked={completed}
                    onChange={() => {
                      toggleChangeHandler(record);
                    }}
                  />
                  <span className="ml-2">{completed ? "Aktif" : "Pasif"}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          },
        },
```

My Data İn Table :

```
[
    {
      "PartnerId": 1,
      "ParentId": 3,
      "PageType": 1,
      "PageTypeText": "İçerik",
      "ModuleId": 1,
      "Name": "anasayfa",
      "Description": "anasayfa açıklama",
      "SummaryText": "açıklama anasayfa",
      "Sort": 1,
      "Status": true,
      "Url": "anasayfa/url",
      "SubPageCount": 1,
      "Module": null,
      "Id": 2,
      "CreatedDate": "2021-08-09T13:01:29.1353202+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": null,
      "UpdatedDate": "2021-08-09T13:13:52.7318892+00:00",
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "IsDelete": false
    },
    {
      "PartnerId": 2,
      "ParentId": 3,
      "PageType": 1,
      "PageTypeText": "İçerik",
      "ModuleId": 1,
      "Name": "hakkimizda",
      "Description": "hakkimizda açıklama",
      "SummaryText": "açıklama hakkimizda",
      "Sort": 1,
      "Status": true,
      "Url": "hakkimizda/url",
      "SubPageCount": 2,
      "Module": null,
      "Id": 3,
      "CreatedDate": "2021-08-09T13:02:20.5230713+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": null,
      "UpdatedDate": "2021-08-09T13:02:20.5230713+00:00",
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "IsDelete": false
    },
    {
      "PartnerId": 1,
      "ParentId": null,
      "PageType": 1,
      "PageTypeText": "İçerik",
      "ModuleId": null,
      "Name": "test",
      "Description": "<p>aaaa</p>",
      "SummaryText": "xaxax",
      "Sort": 0,
      "Status": true,
      "Url": "ppdpd-aaa",
      "SubPageCount": 1,
      "Module": null,
      "Id": 18,
      "CreatedDate": "2021-08-09T14:39:02.6971997+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": null,
      "UpdatedDate": "2021-08-10T11:25:49.2585733+00:00",
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "IsDelete": false
    },
    {
      "PartnerId": 1,
      "ParentId": 2,
      "PageType": 1,
      "PageTypeText": "İçerik",
      "ModuleId": null,
      "Name": "anasayfa alt",
      "Description": "<p>vavavava</p>",
      "SummaryText": "aaaa",
      "Sort": 0,
      "Status": true,
      "Url": "anasayfa-alt",
      "SubPageCount": 0,
      "Module": null,
      "Id": 19,
      "CreatedDate": "2021-08-09T14:42:23.5662338+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": null,
      "UpdatedDate": "2021-08-09T14:42:23.5662338+00:00",
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "IsDelete": false
    },
    {
      "PartnerId": 1,
      "ParentId": 18,
      "PageType": 1,
      "PageTypeText": "İçerik",
      "ModuleId": null,
      "Name": "Yeni İsim Edit",
      "Description": "false",
      "SummaryText": "xaxax",
      "Sort": 0,
      "Status": false,
      "Url": "yeni-isim-edit",
      "SubPageCount": 0,
      "Module": null,
      "Id": 20,
      "CreatedDate": "2021-08-09T14:57:45.9594208+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": null,
      "UpdatedDate": "2021-08-10T10:46:58.1093065+00:00",
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "IsDelete": false
    },
    {
      "PartnerId": 1,
      "ParentId": 22,
      "PageType": 1,
      "PageTypeText": "İçerik",
      "ModuleId": null,
      "Name": "Alt Sayfasın sen",
      "Description": "<p>Açıklandın</p>",
      "SummaryText": "Sen de özetsin",
      "Sort": 0,
      "Status": true,
      "Url": "alt-sayfasin-sen",
      "SubPageCount": 1,
      "Module": null,
      "Id": 23,
      "CreatedDate": "2021-08-09T15:07:28.9230468+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": null,
      "UpdatedDate": "2021-08-09T15:07:28.9230468+00:00",
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "IsDelete": false
    },
    {
      "PartnerId": 1,
      "ParentId": 22,
      "PageType": 1,
      "PageTypeText": "İçerik",
      "ModuleId": null,
      "Name": "Sen de yeni alt sayfasınx",
      "Description": "<p>vfvfvfv</p>",
      "SummaryText": "Yeni özet",
      "Sort": 0,
      "Status": true,
      "Url": "sen-de-yeni-alt-sayfasinx",
      "SubPageCount": 0,
      "Module": null,
      "Id": 24,
      "CreatedDate": "2021-08-09T15:10:54.1260897+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": null,
      "UpdatedDate": "2021-08-09T15:20:27.8274011+00:00",
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "IsDelete": false
    },
    {
      "PartnerId": 1,
      "ParentId": 23,
      "PageType": 1,
      "PageTypeText": "İçerik",
      "ModuleId": null,
      "Name": "tata",
      "Description": "<p>Açıklandın</p>",
      "SummaryText": "xaxa",
      "Sort": 0,
      "Status": true,
      "Url": "tata",
      "SubPageCount": 0,
      "Module": null,
      "Id": 26,
      "CreatedDate": "2021-08-09T15:32:44.5994226+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": null,
      "UpdatedDate": "2021-08-09T15:33:01.1374545+00:00",
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "IsDelete": false
    },
    {
      "PartnerId": 1,
      "ParentId": null,
      "PageType": 1,
      "PageTypeText": "İçerik",
      "ModuleId": null,
      "Name": "Anasayfa",
      "Description": "<p>Aaaa</p>",
      "SummaryText": "Özet",
      "Sort": 0,
      "Status": false,
      "Url": "anasayfa",
      "SubPageCount": 1,
      "Module": null,
      "Id": 28,
      "CreatedDate": "2021-08-10T06:09:26.2965003+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": null,
      "UpdatedDate": "2021-08-10T11:28:37.7050103+00:00",
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "IsDelete": false
    },
    {
      "PartnerId": 1,
      "ParentId": 28,
      "PageType": 1,
      "PageTypeText": "İçerik",
      "ModuleId": null,
      "Name": "Alt Sayfa",
      "Description": "<p>Aaaa</p>",
      "SummaryText": "aaaa",
      "Sort": 0,
      "Status": true,
      "Url": "alt-sayfa",
      "SubPageCount": 0,
      "Module": null,
      "Id": 29,
      "CreatedDate": "2021-08-10T06:09:42.5444548+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": null,
      "UpdatedDate": "2021-08-10T06:09:42.5444548+00:00",
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "IsDelete": false
    }
  ],
```

My State:

```
   const [list, setListData] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
ApiService.FetchService(
                `URL`,
                "GET"
              )
                .then((data) => {
                  setListData(data);
},[props])
//ApiService.FetchService simply fetching data and sending result.
```

Comment: Please show the data of tabe

Comment: @Viet I add my data's. Can you check again please ?

Comment: where are uou store this data?

Comment: @Viet yes i taking it with API then i setting it some State

Comment: Can you show your state?

Comment: @Viet i edit my question but on my toggle i dont using my state. I just using for have data on table. But on record field on my Column its show my row data. So i can access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can update status like this:

```
const toggleChangeHandler = (value) => {
  value.Status = !value.Status;
  setListData((preState) =>
    preState.map((item) => (item.Id === value.Id ? { ...item, Status: !item.Status } : item)),
  );
};
```